# Cannot new create sonarqube user

Tags: sonarqube

I am running sonarqube 8.9.1.44547 and it is connected to a sql server database. My problem is when I try to add a new user, on the web interface, it does nothing. When I click on the create button there is no pop-up or anything to tell me what I am missing. I can also see in the database that the users are not being created. Please help.

Comment: I would check with browser developer tools (under F12) whether there is any error or request blocked by some adblocker.

Comment: @raspy I checked. There are no errors and I don't have a adblocker installed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue now. I used Firefox and it didn't work.

Now I use Google Chrome and now i can create User.

Comment: Same here, does not work in FF.

I guess they did not run code check themselves on create user page. :)

Comment: I could not manage it but a friend of mine did by doing this